# angular orderBy 2 order for one field

Tags: angularjs

I tried looking for this online but had no success, I'm not too sure if I'm not looking for the right thing or whatnot, but hopefully someone can help me with this.

I have a set of data that have common keys `sequence` and `timestamp_created`. The sequences can be any number between 0 to 8.

What I want is sort the data by order of `sequence` but in this order:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0

Then I want to order by `timestamp_created`

I know to do `orderBy: ['sequence','timestamp_create']` if I want to order by 0 - 8 in that order. But how do I put 0 at the end of the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest changing the `sequence` values from 0 to 10 in the controller.